# VueJs Grouping all same validator as one

Tags: javascript, vue.js

After installing [`vuelidate.js.org`](http://vuelidate.js.org) package for `VueJs`, I have this validator in script:

```js
}), Validations: {
    name: {
        required, minLength: minLength(3), maxLength: maxLength(50)
    },
    family: {
        required, minLength: minLength(3), maxLength: maxLength(50)
    },
    website: {
        required, minLength: minLength(3), maxLength: maxLength(50)
    },
    instagram_page: {
        required, minLength: minLength(3), maxLength: maxLength(50)
    },
    telegram_id: {
        required, minLength: minLength(3), maxLength: maxLength(50)
    },
}
```

However, we can define validator for each form fields. How can i group them as one?

As you can see in this code, I have the same validator for all form fields. How can i do that with one validator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
validations: {
    password: {
      required,
      minLength: minLength(6)
    },
    repeatPassword: {
      sameAsPassword: sameAs('password')
    }
  }
```